# use `fields.Nested` in marshmallow to only nest PART of the schema

Tags: python, serialization, schema, field, marshalling

So I have a question when I tried to use `fields.Nested` in marshmallow, I want to use `only` to only extract parts of the schema to the field, but it just doesn't work and it didn't give me an error either(which should mean it recognized only?), so I am not sure why.

version of marshamallow: 3.0.0b11

```
class ChildSchema(Schema):
    attrA = fields.String(example="a"),
    
    attrB = fields.Integer(example=1),

class ParentSchema(Schema):
    attrC = fields.Nested(ChildSchema, only=["attrA"])
```

What I expect is:

```
"attrC":{
   "attrA": "a"
}
```

But instead, I see:

```
"attrC":{
   "attrA": "a",
   "attrB": 1,
}
```

Reference: https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/3.0/nesting.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not clear on what `example` is doing in your schema. It's not a parameter for a `Schema` object. Also, it's not clear how you're calling your schema and trying to display your results. However, the following produces the desired result:

```
from marshmallow import Schema, fields, pprint

class ChildSchema(Schema):
    attrA = fields.Str(example="a")
    attrB = fields.Integer(example=1)

class ParentSchema(Schema):
    attrC = fields.Nested(ChildSchema, only=['attrA'])

schema = ParentSchema()
result = schema.dump({'attrC': {'attrA': 'five', 'attrB': 5}})

pprint(result)
#{'attrC': {'attrA': 'five'}}
```

Comment: The example is because I am using swagger ui, but the reason that I didn't think it work is because I tested in the wrong way. So thanks for showing me how to test it.